# Execute code at the end of the loop execution of zf2

Tags: php, triggers, zend-framework2, listener

I want to execute the code at the last moment to perform a hand sql commit.

What is the equivalent method "dispatchLoopShutdown" that was available in Zend Framework 1.x? In zf 1.x we could do in the global bootstrap, What is the equivalent in zf2?

Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ZF2 the whole application flow is controlled by events. I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish and mean by a 'hand sql commit'? You could write a listener and listen to the [finish](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.mvc.mvc-event.html#mvcevent-event-finish) event which is the last event that is triggered before the response is returned to the user, if you need to hook in somewhere else in the MVC application flow you can simply listen to another event. See [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.mvc.mvc-event.html#order-of-events) for a list of all available events.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer. This is exactly what I do, I added a listener that listens "EVENT_FINISH". The problem is that each module listen to this event, so I'm not absolutely sure that this is indeed the last event.

When an event triggers, all listeners catch the event. There is no order so I can not be sure that this is the last. I need to know this in order to commit my transaction at the end of the page and make sure everything went well before commit.

Comment: Glad it helped. You can give your listeners a priority. Just give it a low priority (like -10000) so you are sure it is the last executed listener.